# Receiving an empty request with Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having trouble receiving a simple object that's been turned into JSON. It shows up in the `console.log` as a `{}`, nothing more. I'll just refer to the server code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.listen(3000);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/api", (request, response) => {
  console.log("You got a request");
  console.log(request.body);
});
```

And the `index.html` code:

```
        console.log("geolocation available");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          const lat = position.coords.latitude;
          const long = position.coords.longitude;

          const data = { lat, long };
          const options = {
            method: "POST",
            header: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
          };
          fetch("/api", options);
        });
      } else {
        console.log("geolocation not available");
      }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think in `fetch` options, you are supposed to pass `headers`, not `header`

Comment: @thammada, that's the answer! Help me mark you as solved.

Comment: Zabeeh just got the same answer, you can mark that answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a type in index.html, it should be "headers" not "header"

```
const options = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { // Not header
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
          };
```